# USB null modem cable using 2 x PL2303: are resistors necessary?

Tags: usb

I've built a USB to USB null modem cable using 2 x Prolific USB to serial "converters". I use this cable for debugging linux kernel crashes (in the same way that people have tradionally used "serial to serial" null modem cables) and it works perfectly. I have incorporated 3 x 100 ohm resistors into the cable thus:

```
                        /  Tx - 100 ohm resistor - Rx  \
Computer A USB - PL2303 - Gnd - 100 ohm resistor - Gnd - PL2303 - Computer B USB
                        \  Rx - 100 ohm resistor - Tx  /
```

I incorporated the 3 resistors because of something that I read on the internet, but I can no longer remember why or where I read it.

I have 3 questions:

1. Are the 3 resistors necessary?
2. (perhaps more importantly) how do you know (whether the 3 resistors are necessary)?
3. Is a resistor necessary if I perform a loopback "test" on 1 single cable (i.e. by connecting its Tx pin to its Rx pin)?

(For bonus points, what tags should I apply to this question?)

I've searched electronics.stackexchange.com for relevant questions, and I've already found:

[USB data serial termination resistors. Need them for STM32F2 micro? If so, what wattage?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/177061/usb-data-serial-termination-resistors-need-them-for-stm32f2-micro-if-so-what)

[USB termination on STM32F437xx](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/134743/usb-termination-on-stm32f437xx)

[TTL RS-232 current limiting](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/49174/ttl-rs-232-current-limiting)

but I'm reasonably certain that these questions are not duplicates of my question(s).

Comment: I think you could well apply the reasoning from the third question you dragged out of the archive here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No they are not needed for it to work. TTL serial inputs are designed to be high impedance and do not need the lines to have a specific termination resistance or anything. Most TTL UARTS are normally directly connected.

They do help if the lines somehow get shorted out, limiting the current to V/100 = I amps. Assuming 5 V, that's 0.05 amps or 50 milliamps, much better than a dead short.

Answer (score 1):

The three resistors give you some protection from ground loops, but if the usb cable has the shield connected at both ends they are probably not needed.

As for tags, `UART`,`USB` and possibly `Coupling`